# which code editor provides these features

Tags: javascript, editor

I have been trying sublime for half year but the lack of some things is just too sad.

The things i would like (the least)...

- AutoHinting/AutoCompleteing just like in chrome console.
- Auto brackets close
- Live Preview
- Auto quotes close
- Multiple cursors
- Multiple windows mode
- Beautify (legit and customizable one)
- and other basic features...like proper auto indentations, color, in file funcs hinting/jumping/definition.
- Also support emmet.

Comment: why can't there be code editor based on webkit...

Comment: I'm rather fond of [`Komodo Edit`](http://komodoide.com/) but not sure that it 100% meets those requirements, the IDE version does more, but then it is not free.

Comment: webstorm 7 is pretty good